# Generate swagger.json file after build failed

Tags: asp.net, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and I'm trying to generate the `swagger.json` file after build instead of at runtime.

I was trying to use `dotnet new tool-manifest` and then `dotnet tool install --version 6.5.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli` and then add this lines to my `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="CreateSwaggerJson" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ./swagger/v1/swagger.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

but when I build my project I get an error:

> The command "dotnet swagger tofile --output ./swagger/v1/swagger.json bin\Debug\net6.0\MyProj.dll v1" exited with code -532462766

I don't have any other information besides that.

I was also trying to download the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli from the NuGet package manager manually but I get errors also there:

> Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.5.0' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'MyProj'.

and also

> Invalid project-package combination for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.5.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by changing the versions of Swashbuckle packages to 6.4.0, which is the version that supports .NET 6.0