# Error: "MSB3073 The command "dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger_v1.json bin\Debug\net6.0\TestSwaggerGenWithDotnetSix.dll v1" exited with code 1."

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, swagger, post-build-event

I want to generate the swagger file *(OpenAPI specification json file)* post building my API. I've added this <Target> XML script in my .csproj file to generate the swagger file but I get the mentioned error message without any description.

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger_v1.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" />
</Target>
```

But I get the following error:

`MSB3073 The command "dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger_v1.json bin\Debug\net6.0\TestSwaggerGenWithDotnetSix.dll v1" exited with code 1.`

**Tried** [this stackoverflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075279/how-do-i-fix-msb3073-error-in-my-post-build-event) and [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914339/error-msb3073-how-do-i-fix-this) as well but nothing worked out for me.

**Tried** [downgrading the swagger version from 6.5 to 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264929/generate-swagger-json-file-after-build-failed), still getting the same issue.

I also saw some stackoverflow answer where they were writing the swagger file using File.Write during the builder.build event but it fails on server as we don't have file writing permissions in Azure Build Pipeline during Build process.

```
ISwaggerProvider swaggerService = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>(); 
OpenApiDocument doc = swaggerService.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/"); 
string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0); 
File.WriteAllText("swagger_v1.json", swaggerFile);
```

My swaggerGenDoc and SwaggerUi are correct as without the above XML script, the project runs smoothly.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "v1",
        Version = "v1"
    });
});
```

.Net version: 8

Swagger version: Swashbuckle 6.5

Comment: Try restore "dotnet tool restore" and execute again.

Comment: @Jag If you notice, dotnet tool restore is already added to exec command post every build already. This does not help it seems.

Comment: Do you have appsettings.local.json in this case if it is searching for environment variable settings.

Comment: @Jag it's already there with all the key-value in place.

Comment: @Jag I've put `appsettings.development.json` with all the configs in place. still it throws this issue.

Comment: There is nothing much.  recheck you have installed all packages and if  you settings are not readable from appsettings.  try adding it in launch settings and make sure it is accessible. and hope you set aspdotnet environment to local.